# Invalid S3 Access Key Id, Stopping Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci

My build on travis is failing to deploy.  I using the same s3 access key id as another build that is working.  Do I have to use different access keys for each build project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every encrypted key in your `.travis.yml` must be unique per repo.
So even if key `shjowjdjpakk19o` works on `test/test`, it will **not** work on `test/nother-test`.

You can create a new key by deleting the old one and with the travis tool run `travis encrypt SECRET-KEY` and copying in the new key.

Comment: Thanks again Josh.  It would be great if error codes were returned as well which could then be matched to set of possible solutions.